# Dir function in VB6 - Error 5

Tags: vb6, dir

I have an issue with the `Dir` function.

```
Private Sub InitFileElvt()
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim find As Boolean
    Dim trouve As Boolean
    trouve = False
    fileName = Dir(THEORIQUE & "\" & LibPie & CftMot & _ 
               Mid(NoPlan, 13, 1) & Mid(VERPIE, 1, 1) & "\") 'It works here
    Do While fileName > "" And Not trouve
        If IsElvtFile(fileName) Then
            trouve = True
            pathFileElvt = THEORIQUE & "\" & fileName
        End If
        fileName = Dir() 'An error here
    Loop
    If Not trouve Then
        pathFileElvt = "empty"
    End If
End Sub

Private Function IsElvtFile(ByVal fileName As String) As Boolean 
    Dim lengthDeb As Integer
    lengthDeb = Len(LibPie) + Len(CftMot) + 1
    IsElvtFile = Left(fileName, lengthDeb) = LibPie + CftMot + Mid(NoPlan, 13, 1) And _
                 Right(fileName, 4) = ".ELV"
End Function
```

The first call to `Dir` give me a file from the folder. Good. But the second call give me `Run-Time Error '5': Invalid Procedure Call or Argument`

What i'm missing about the `Dir` Function? Apparently, that's how it have to be used.

When i'm in debug mode, in the line `Do While fileName > "" And Not trouve`, my watch on dir returns the next file. After this line is executed, my watch shows the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was other watch in `Dir(otherPath)`...
I've removed them and now it works

Comment: Do you mean you find a solution / workaround? What exactly did you remove that fixed the problem?

Comment: @SiyonDP I'm sorry I don't remember my code at all.. (4 years since I coded in VB6). But I think that in another path of my code there was a wrong call to the `Dir` function